# Добавление указателя this в вектор указателей на объект

Tags: c++

Есть класс, содержащий поля данных и вектор указателей на объекты этого класса.
Указатели добавляются в вектор при создании нового объекта:

```
using namespace std;

class ClassName {
public:
    int x;
    static vector<ClassName*>ptrs;
    ClassName::ClassName(int xx) : x(xx) {
        ptrs.push_back(new ClassName);
        ptrs.back() = this;
    }
    ClassName::ClassName() {

    }
};
```

В конструкторе инициализируется значение данных, а в векторе создается новый указатель, которому сразу же присваивается значение this;
при выполнении следующего кода - создание 10 объектов и вывод значения их данных через вектор:

```
vector<ClassName*>ClassName::ptrs;
int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        ClassName::ClassName(rand());
        cout << ClassName::ptrs.back()->x << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << ClassName::ptrs[i]->x << " ";
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

в первом цикле, когда значение последнего элемента выводится сразу, получается:

```
41 18467 6334 26500 19169 15724 11478 29358 26962 24464
```

а во втором:

```
24464 24464 24464 24464 24464 24464 24464 24464 24464 24464
```

видно, что значение указателей в векторе всегда равны последнему указателю в в этом векторе. Почему так получается, и как правильно сделать занесение указателя на новый объект в вектор?

Comment: Вам необходимо решить какую-то конкретную задачу, или же это просто пример для обучения ?) Если первое - то опишите ее.

Comment: И начните с вывода cout'ов в конструкторах и деструкторе - у вас утечка памяти.

Comment: Я просто пытаюсь реализовать схему,  в которой имеется доступ ко всем объектам через вектор указателей. В дальнейшем объекты будут интенсивно добавляться и убираться в зависимости от значений их данных.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот эти две строчки:

```
ptrs.push_back(new ClassName);
ptrs.back() = this;
```

Означают буквально следующее:

1. Среда, выдели память под `ClassName`, вызови его конструктор и верни мне указатель.
2. Вектор, положи в конец себя указатель, который я тебе передал в аргументах `push_back`
3. Вектор, я не знаю, что там у тебя лежит последним элементом, но теперь там будет лежать `this`.

Таким образом, Вы выделяете память под объект, сохраняете указатель и тут же его затираете. Поэтому, правильно будет писать так:

```
ptrs.push_back(this);
```

И всё, больше ничего не нужно.

---

Нашёл ещё проблему: вот Вы сохраняете `this` в векторе, но создаёте Вы элементы на стеке, которые сразу же уничтожаются. Поэтому у Вас, в сущности, неопределённое поведение. Именно поэтому, в первом случае, Вы видите ожидаемые значения: в каждом раунде цикла на одном и том же месте стека создаётся новый объект, значение которого Вы и выводите. Но на следующей итерации это место в стеке обновляется данными нового объекта и, поэтому, второй цикл видит только последнее значение на стеке. Повторяю, то, что это работает — просто совпадение, Ваша программа имеет неопределённое поведение.

Как можно исправить:

```
int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        new ClassName(rand());
        cout << ClassName::ptrs.back()->x << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << ClassName::ptrs[i]->x << " ";
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        delete ClassName::ptrs[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Это всё выглядит ужасно, но хоть будет работать как Вы того хотели и поведение будет предсказуемо.

Comment: Какие именно объекты удаляются? Основная задача заключалась не в выводе значений, а в сохранении указателя на новоиспеченный объект.

Comment: @derzz, вот в этой строчке: `ClassName::ClassName(rand());` создаётся временный объект, который сразу же удаляется(по завершении выражения). Указатели на новые объект лучше сохранять в том месте, где Вы объекты создаёте. Сохранение `this` указателей это в 99.99% случаев ошибка

Comment: this предназначен только для работы с данными внутри объекта, так? изменив конструктор                                                                              `ClassName* buf = new ClassName;
  buf->x = xx;
  ptrs.push_back(buf);` в вектор будет добавляться указатель на объект, у которого данные такие, как и у создаваемого в конструкторе, то есть копия. Есть ли способ добавлять указатель на сам объект?

Comment: @derzz, `this` это указатель на текущий объект. Его предназначение определяется программистом. Внутри объекта нет необходимости явно использовать `this` — к полям объект можно обращаться и без него(точнее без явного его использование). С другой стороны, извне объекта, даже сохранив `this` нельзя достучаться до приватных частей объекта — `this` это просто указатель.

Comment: Вам не кажется, странным то, что он создает элементы на стеке (причем создаются `rvalue-ссылки`, которые даже не доживают до `cout`), а затем хранит на них ссылку (по факту ссылку на невалидную область памяти). Я так понимаю факт того, что выводится именно последнее занесенное значение является чистым совпадением с тем, что компилятор создает новые экземпляры объекта на стеке именно в той же области памяти, где и располагались его неудачливые предшественники (как видимо, после уничтожения объекта на стеке, его компилятор просто помечает область свободной , но не очищает её).
Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: @StateItPrimitive, Вы всё понимаете правильно, именно так и происходит. Компилятор никогда не вставляет инструкции очистки памяти, если их явно не задать. ОС может обнулять ненужные страницы, но стек всегда в «нужных» страницах, поэтому если никто не перезаписал старое значение, то оно там будет сохраняться.